# Today ExtensionでRealmデータの共有の書き方について

Tags: swift, realm

下記ページなどを参考にアプリとToday Extensionの間でRealmデータの共有をしたいのですが、
https://qiita.com/oidy/items/3bcb26d67a1c4c9d90c7

下記あたりのコードの書き方が分からなくて色々と試しているのですがアプリが落ちたりしています。

```
var config = Realm.Configuration()
let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.example.MyApp")!
config.fileURL = url.appendingPathComponent("db.realm")
```

アプリ側のコードです。

```
// AppDelegate.swift
func setupRealm() {
    var fileNum = 0
    var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration

    var realmFileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("u0.realm")

    let fileMng = FileManager.default

    if !fileMng.fileExists(atPath: realmFileURL.path) {
        realmFileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("u1.realm")
        fileNum = 1
    }

    config.fileURL = realmFileURL
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

    compaction(fileNum: fileNum)
}

func compaction(fileNum: Int) {
    let config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration

    let realmFileURL = config.fileURL!

    var copyFileURL = realmFileURL.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("u1.realm")
    if fileNum == 1 {
        copyFileURL = realmFileURL.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("u0.realm")
    }

    let fileManager = FileManager()
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: realmFileURL.path) {
        autoreleasepool {
            do {
                let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
                try realm.writeCopy(toFile: (copyFileURL as NSURL) as URL)
            } catch {
                let _ = try? fileManager.removeItem(at: realmFileURL)
            }
        }

        let _ = try? fileManager.removeItem(at: realmFileURL)
        let _ = try? fileManager.moveItem(at: copyFileURL, to: realmFileURL)
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {        
    setupRealm()

    return true
}
```

Today Extension側のコードです。

```
// TodayViewController.swift
func widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler: (@escaping (NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {        
    var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration

    var realmFileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("u0.realm")

    let fileMng = FileManager.default

    if !fileMng.fileExists(atPath: realmFileURL.path) {
        realmFileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("u1.realm")
    }

    config.fileURL = realmFileURL
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

    completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.newData)
}
```

環境はXcode 9.1、Swift 4です。
どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エクステンションと本体アプリは別のアプリケーションなので、ドキュメントディレクトリも異なります。あなたのコードではエクステンションと本体アプリのそれぞれ別のドキュメントディレクトリに同じ名前で別のファイルを作成しています。ファイルを共有するためには共有コンテナを設定して同じ場所でファイルを読み書きします。冒頭のコードは共有コンテナのパスを取得し、Realmに設定していますが、その前に共有コンテナがセットアップされている必要があります。共有コンテナの設定は済んでますか？

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi さん 共有コンテナというのはApp Groupのことを指しているのでしょうか？であれば、Xcode上のTargetsの中のアプリとエクステンション共に、Capabilitiesをオンにしてgroup.com.sample.myappのチェックを共に入れています。冒頭のリンク先のページで言えば、「Step 6.1」まで進んでいる状態です。

Comment: App Groupのことを指しています。であればリンク先を参考にApp GroupのディレクトリにRealmファイルを保存するように設定すればエクステンションと本体アプリの両方から同じファイルを読み書きできます。わからないところはなんでしょうか？

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi さん 冒頭の3行のコード部分ですね。下記のコードを
    var configuration = Realm.Configuration()
    let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.example.MyApp")!
    configuration.fileURL = url.appendingPathComponent(String(describing: realmFileURL))
アプリ側とエクステンション側のそれぞれの下記コードの後ろにに追記してみたのですが、データが空で何も表示されませんでした。
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

Comment: `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config`の意味はわかっていますか？

Comment: すみません、まだまだ理解できていないと思いますが、指定した内容をデフォルトで使用するということでしょうか？

Comment: そうです。`Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration`に代入した内容が、それ以降`Realm()`を呼び出す際に使われます。同じ設定を何度も引数として渡す必要がなくなります。理解していないのであれば、まず、リンク先の通りにやってみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi 本文に追記したコードでデータを取得することができました。ご確認いただけましたら幸いです。

Comment: ひとまずはそれで問題ないです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！大変助かりました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記のように修正することでエクステンション側でデータを取得できました。
アプリ側

```
// AppDelegate.swift
var fileNum = 0
var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration

var realmFileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("u0.realm")

let fileMng = FileManager.default

if !fileMng.fileExists(atPath: realmFileURL.path) {
    realmFileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("u1.realm")
    fileNum = 1
}

let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.sample.myapp")!
if fileNum == 0 {
    config.fileURL = url.appendingPathComponent("u0.realm")
} else {
    config.fileURL = url.appendingPathComponent("u1.realm")
}

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

エクステンション側

```
// TodayViewController.swift
var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration

let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.sample.myapp")!
var realmFileURL = url.appendingPathComponent("u0.realm")

let fileMng = FileManager.default
if !fileMng.fileExists(atPath: realmFileURL.path) {
    realmFileURL = url.appendingPathComponent("u1.realm")
}

config.fileURL = realmFileURL
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```